# Transaction commit event handler in Grails

Tags: hibernate, events, grails, commit

Is there a way to get a notification in Grails once a transaction has been committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need a Grails [programmatic transaction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html)

Comment: but how can I tell the transaction was committed? Even a withTransaction closure might be committed later than just after the block was executed

Comment: it'll be commited automatically, if `.setRollbackOnly()` wasn't specified and no exceptions was thrown. You can convinced by looking at Spring TX's TransactionTemplate sources

Comment: If there's already an active transaction then the withTransaction block will join it and not commit. It's unlikely though.